# "I have this problem too" feature

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, answers, unanswered-questions

I have a proposal for a feature that'll help questions where many people have the same problem get more attention.

#### Part 1: "I have this problem too" button

There will be a button on questions labeled "I have this problem too." Only users who do not own this question will be able to press the button.

On every question, next to the button, there'll be text that indicates how many users have this problem. Pressing "I have this problem too" increments the count.

#### Part 2: "Need help" question sort

There'll be a new sort for questions, "need help." This sorts questions by the number of people that have those problems.

#### Part 3: "This solved my problem" button

When a user upvotes an answer to a question that they've pressed the "I have this problem too" button on, a message will appear:

> Did this answer solve your problem? [Yes] [No]

If the user presses "yes," they will be removed from the list of users who have this problem, decrementing the count.

Comment: And how will this "help questions where many people have the same problem get more attention"? (also - why do you think there is a problem to begin with?)

Comment: Part 1: Upvote question. Part 2: If part 1 is widely applied, search for unanswered questions sorted by votes. Part 3: Upvote answer.

Comment: *"help questions where many people have the same problem get more attention."* that's assuming that questions like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18050071/1028804) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2973202/1028804) just don't turn up in any search results, rather than people being too lazy to do any research

Comment: "*I have a proposal for a feature that'll help questions where many people have the same problem get more attention.*" Before suggesting a way to solve a problem, you should first determine if the problem *actually exists* in any real capacity. Oh, I'm sure that there are a non-zero number of unanswered questions that multiple users encounter. But is that a significant enough problem to add a feature like this? What evidence do you have that supports such a change?

Comment: Your proposal fails to explain how the "upvote" button does not adequately address this issue. Is it your claim that there are *poor quality questions* that you otherwise do not want to upvote, yet you have the same problem and want to attach yourself to the question in that way instead? Because that seems goofy. If you really care, edit the question to approve it, then upvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All suggested improvements seem to exist already:

"I have this problem too" button is already there and called "bounty". It also addresses 2 - questions with bounty are shown in its own category.

As for 3 - simple upvote is indication of "this was useful" (almost "This solved my problem"). If user posted bounty - additionally manually assigning bounty to best answer indicates "This solved my problem" (automatic bounty is "not really what I was looking for").